# Comparacion de 2 hash en perl

Tags: perl, hashmap, hash

Tengo 2 tablas de hash, las 2 tablas cuentan con las mismas claves, pero diferentes valores.

Necesito comparar ambos valores de la misma clave y saber la diferencia de valores.

Ejemplo:

Hash 1: clave1 => 5

Hash 1: clave2 => 10

Hash 2: clave1 => 9

Hash 2: clave2 => 4

Diferencia de valores de la clave1 = 4

Diferencia de valores de la clave2 = 6

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que hacer un bucle, digamos, por el primer hash, usando la función keys(). Por ejemplo, dentro de un for().

Dentro del bucle, haces un if() para ver si existe (con exists()) la misma entrada pero en el segundo hash. En ese caso, tomas los dos valores de los dos hash, sacas la diferencia y la muestras.